# Excel Grouping Pivot Table Fields using Win32com in Python

Tags: python, excel, win32com

My code

```
Test = wsPivotTable.Range("B2")
Test.Group(Start=True, End=True, Periods=list([False, False, False, False, True, False, True]))
```

For some reasons, this would only group the Months but not the Years, even though I had the value set to True. Please help!

Comment: Please provide some data so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hello, Please try this:
`Invoice Due Date Currency  Invoice Amount`
`9/30/2021 USD  $19.15`
`8/31/2021 USD  $94.32`
`9/3/2021 USD  $134.89`
`11/30/2021 USD  $320.10`
`10/28/2021 USD  $(225.60)`
`10/30/2021 USD  $15.43 `
`2/23/2022 USD  $4,244.00`


"Invoice Due Date" is the pivot table column field which I am trying to do grouping for Month and Year.